# How to import SSL certificate .CER to IIS 10 when I don't have .PFX and no keys?

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, iis-10

I have only.cer file for SSL certificate which I received from a certificate authority. My original computer, which created the certificate request, got crashed.

- I have to install the certificate in another computer.
- But when I click on Import in the IIS 10, it asks me .pfx extension.
- I have only a .cer extension file. I don't have any keys to make .cer to .pfx because my original computer is damaged.

Is there a way to install the .cer to the new machine?

Comment: The current certificate you get is useless without the private key. You have to generate a new private key and then certificate request. The certificate authority can generate another certificate for you afterwards. Quite common but you should learn how to back up private keys now.

Comment: The cer extension file stores the public key of the certificate, which is used to verify the token and client identity. The pfx extension file is the most important part of the certificate, storing the public key and the private key. Therefore, the pfx extension file is very important in the process of importing and using the certificate. You can use the cer extension file and the private key to create the pfx extension file through the OpenSSL client, and then import it into IIS.